# Aggregating parameters with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I'm working on jersey framework.. and for API we are sending multiformdata like this

```
public Response get(@HeaderParam("usrId") int usrId, @HeaderParam("id") int id, @FormDataParam("workFile") InputStream workFileStream, @FormDataParam("workFile") FormDataContentDisposition workFileDetail, @FormDataParam("workNotes") String workNotes, @FormDataParam("conditionFile") InputStream conditionFileStream,
@FormDataParam("conditionFile") FormDataContentDisposition conditionFileDatails, @FormDataParam("conditionNotes") String conditionNotes, @FormDataParam("DesignConditionFile") InputStream designConditionStream, @FormDataParam("DesignConditionFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDesignCondition, @FormDataParam("desgnConditionNotes") String desgnConditionNotes,
@FormDataParam("drawingFile") InputStream drawingFileStream, @FormDataParam("drawingFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDrawing, @FormDataParam("desgnDrawingNotes") String desgnDrawingNotes, @FormDataParam("listMakesFile") InputStream listMakesStream, @FormDataParam("listMakesFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileListMakes, @FormDataParam("listMakesNotes") String listMakesNotes,
@FormDataParam("paymentTermsFile") InputStream paymentTermsStream, @FormDataParam("paymentTermsFile") FormDataContentDisposition filePaymentTerms, @FormDataParam("paymentTermsNotes") String paymentTermsNotes, @FormDataParam("bankGuaranteFile") InputStream bankGuaranteStream, @FormDataParam("bankGuaranteFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileBankGuarante,
@FormDataParam("bankGuarnteeNotes") String bankGuarnteeNotes, @FormDataParam("commPointPrjReq") Boolean commPointPrjReq, @FormDataParam("commPointPrjTimeline") String commPointPrjTimeline, @FormDataParam("prjClauseFile") InputStream prjClauseFileStream, @FormDataParam("prjClauseFile") FormDataContentDisposition filePrjClause, @FormDataParam("prjClause") String prjClauseNotes){

.....code

}
```

for one API we r sending so many files.. and for defining the parameters it'll consume 5 files..

can we define this formadata in seperate input class(input.java) and call the input class in the API like this

```
public Response get(@HeaderParam("usrId") int usrId, @HeaderParam("id") int id, Input input)
{

............code
}
```

and can we define input class like this

```
public class input
{

@FormDataParam("workFile") InputStream workFileStream, @FormDataParam("workFile") FormDataContentDisposition workFileDetail, @FormDataParam("workNotes") String workNotes, @FormDataParam("conditionFile") InputStream conditionFileStream,
@FormDataParam("conditionFile") FormDataContentDisposition conditionFileDatails, 
@FormDataParam("conditionNotes") String conditionNotes, @FormDataParam("DesignConditionFile") InputStream designConditionStream, @FormDataParam("DesignConditionFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDesignCondition, 
@FormDataParam("desgnConditionNotes") String desgnConditionNotes,
@FormDataParam("drawingFile") InputStream drawingFileStream, @FormDataParam("drawingFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDrawing, @FormDataParam("desgnDrawingNotes") String desgnDrawingNotes, @FormDataParam("listMakesFile") InputStream listMakesStream, @FormDataParam("listMakesFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileListMakes, @FormDataParam("listMakesNotes") String listMakesNotes,
@FormDataParam("paymentTermsFile") InputStream paymentTermsStream, @FormDataParam("paymentTermsFile") FormDataContentDisposition filePaymentTerms, 
@FormDataParam("paymentTermsNotes") String paymentTermsNotes, @FormDataParam("bankGuaranteFile") InputStream bankGuaranteStream, @FormDataParam("bankGuaranteFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileBankGuarante,
@FormDataParam("bankGuarnteeNotes") String bankGuarnteeNotes, @FormDataParam("commPointPrjReq") Boolean commPointPrjReq, @FormDataParam("commPointPrjTimeline") String commPointPrjTimeline, @FormDataParam("prjClauseFile") InputStream prjClauseFileStream, @FormDataParam("prjClauseFile") FormDataContentDisposition filePrjClause, @FormDataParam("prjClause") String prjClauseNotes

}
```

Comment: Try using [`BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html). The annotation can be used as a "parameter aggregator" that can be injected into a resource class field, property or resource method parameter. It can be used as following:

### 1. Wrap the parameters into a class

Create a POJO to aggregate your parameters:

```java
public class Input {

    @FormDataParam("workFile") 
    private InputStream workFileStream;

    @FormDataParam("workFile")
    private FormDataContentDisposition workFileDetail;

    @FormDataParam("workNotes") 
    private String workNotes;

    @FormDataParam("conditionFile") 
    private InputStream conditionFileStream;

    @FormDataParam("conditionFile") 
    private FormDataContentDisposition conditionFileDatails;

    @FormDataParam("conditionNotes")
    private String conditionNotes;

    @FormDataParam("DesignConditionFile")
    private InputStream designConditionStream;

    @FormDataParam("DesignConditionFile")
    private FormDataContentDisposition fileDesignCondition;

    @FormDataParam("desgnConditionNotes")
    private String desgnConditionNotes;

    @FormDataParam("drawingFile")
    private InputStream drawingFileStream;

    @FormDataParam("drawingFile")
    private FormDataContentDisposition fileDrawing;

    @FormDataParam("desgnDrawingNotes")
    private String desgnDrawingNotes;

    @FormDataParam("listMakesFile")
    private InputStream listMakesStream;

    @FormDataParam("listMakesFile")
    private FormDataContentDisposition fileListMakes;

    @FormDataParam("listMakesNotes")
    private String listMakesNotes;

    @FormDataParam("paymentTermsFile")
    private InputStream paymentTermsStream;

    @FormDataParam("paymentTermsFile")
    private FormDataContentDisposition filePaymentTerms;

    @FormDataParam("paymentTermsNotes")
    private String paymentTermsNotes;

    @FormDataParam("bankGuaranteFile")
    private InputStream bankGuaranteStream;

    @FormDataParam("bankGuaranteFile")
    private FormDataContentDisposition fileBankGuarante;

    @FormDataParam("bankGuarnteeNotes")
    private String bankGuarnteeNotes;

    @FormDataParam("commPointPrjReq")
    private Boolean commPointPrjReq;

    @FormDataParam("commPointPrjTimeline")
    private String commPointPrjTimeline;

    @FormDataParam("prjClauseFile")
    private InputStream prjClauseFileStream;

    @FormDataParam("prjClauseFile")
    private FormDataContentDisposition filePrjClause;

    @FormDataParam("prjClause")
    private String prjClauseNotes;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters ommited
}
```

### 2. Change the resource method to use the "parameter aggregator" class

Use the above defined POJO as a parameter of your resource method:

```java
@POST
public Response upload(@HeaderParam("usrId") int usrId,
                       @HeaderParam("id") int id,
                       @BeanParam Input input) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That Helped a lot.. Thans

Comment: @GaneshBhagavath So don't forget accepting the answer ;)

Comment: ya sure.. once again thank you... can u pleasae explain how to test this in restclent or postman?

Comment: @GaneshBhagavath If my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it.